# Rails 3 - Routing error when submitting forms using nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resources, nested

I'm completely new to rails and I'm having a lot of trouble getting my nested resource/models to work. I'm getting a routing error whenever I try to submit my form.

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"tests", :test_suite_id=>#<Test id: 8, name: "1", test_type: "1", result_type: "1", input: "1", created_at: "2012-06-29 07:01:11", updated_at: "2012-06-29 07:01:11", date: "1", test_suite_id: 4>}
```

Can someone explain to me why there is too occurrences of test_suite_id in the exception output and why is the action "show" instead of "index"? When I submit the form, I want to go back to the index /test_suites/:test_suite_id/tests.

Below is all the relevant code:

routes.rb

```
  resources :test_suites do
    resources :tests
  end
```

tests_controller.rb

```
class TestsController < ApplicationController
    # GET /tests
    # GET /tests.json
    def index

        @testsuite = TestSuite.find(params[:test_suite_id])
        @tests = @testsuite.tests

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html # index.html.erb
            format.json { render json: @tests }
        end
    end

    # GET /tests/1
    # GET /tests/1.json
    def show
        @testsuite = TestSuite.find(params[:test_suite_id])
        @test = @testsuite.tests.find(params[:id])

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html # show.html.erb
            format.json { render json: @test }
        end
    end

    # GET /tests/new
    # GET /tests/new.json
    def new
        @testsuite = TestSuite.find(params[:test_suite_id])
        @test = @testsuite.tests.build

        #@test = Test.new
        @test.build_hardware
        @test.build_software

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html # new.html.erb
            format.json { render json: @test }
        end
    end

    # GET /tests/1/edit
    def edit
        @test = Test.find(params[:id])
    end

    # POST /tests
    # POST /tests.json
    def create

        @testsuite = TestSuite.find(params[:test_suite_id])
        @test = @testsuite.tests.build(params[:test])

        respond_to do |format|
            if @test.save
                flash[:notice] = "Test Added Succesfully"
                format.html { redirect_to [:test_suite, @test], notice: 'Test was successfully created.' }
                format.json { render json: @test, status: :created, location: @test }
                else
                format.html { render action: "new" }
                format.json { render json: @test.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([:test_suite, @test], :action => "index") do |f| %>
  <% if @test.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@test.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this test from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @test.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <br />
  <h2>Test information</h2>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :test_type %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :test_type %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :result_type %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :result_type %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :date %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :date %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :input %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :input %>
  </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>


  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

rake routes:

```
     test_suite_new GET    /test_suite/new(.:format)                            test_suite#new
    test_suite_tests GET    /test_suites/:test_suite_id/tests(.:format)          tests#index
                     POST   /test_suites/:test_suite_id/tests(.:format)          tests#create
 new_test_suite_test GET    /test_suites/:test_suite_id/tests/new(.:format)      tests#new
edit_test_suite_test GET    /test_suites/:test_suite_id/tests/:id/edit(.:format) tests#edit
     test_suite_test GET    /test_suites/:test_suite_id/tests/:id(.:format)      tests#show
                     PUT    /test_suites/:test_suite_id/tests/:id(.:format)      tests#update
                     DELETE /test_suites/:test_suite_id/tests/:id(.:format)      tests#destroy
         test_suites GET    /test_suites(.:format)                               test_suites#index
                     POST   /test_suites(.:format)                               test_suites#create
      new_test_suite GET    /test_suites/new(.:format)                           test_suites#new
     edit_test_suite GET    /test_suites/:id/edit(.:format)                      test_suites#edit
          test_suite GET    /test_suites/:id(.:format)                           test_suites#show
                     PUT    /test_suites/:id(.:format)                           test_suites#update
                     DELETE /test_suites/:id(.:format)                           test_suites#destroy
                root        /                                                    home#index
```

Comment: hi @vesselli, I'm not sure I've fully followed what you are trying to achieve, perhaps you could add a quick description of your goal to the question. But from looking through your code, I wonder if you are confusing nested resources and nested forms? Take a look at http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources/ and http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the dis-congruity of these two lines:

`resources :test_suites do`

`<%= form_for([:test_suite, @test], :action => "index") do |f| %>`

The use of `resources` (as opposed to `resource`) implies a collection (as opposed to a singular resource). Resources nested within do not belong to the collection, though, they must belong to a specific member in the collection.

In your `form_for([:test_suite, @test])` you are saying you want a form that belongs to a singular resource called "test_suite".

You either need to change your parent resource to singular, or pass in a specific `test_suite` instance (ie: `form_for([@a_test_suite_instance, @test])`).

Comment: I ended figuring out my problem, which seemed to be completely unrelated. My index view for tests had some incorrect paths, which was why I was getting a routing error.